# Install node_modules for Angular Apps into a different folder

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, node-modules, windows-11

I've a plain Angular project with Angular CLI on Windows. Everything works fine.

But: Since I sync my development folder with OneDrive, the 20k files from node_modules are very annoying.

Thus: How can I install the node_modules into a different location like "c:\temp\my_app_node_modules" and leave everything else (src, dist, app, ...) where it?

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to use Git and some online service like GitHub to sync your source code. Then you just install dependencies on each machine separately.

Comment: I'm using git - but it's a little bit more complicated, since there are many more project belonging files, that are not effective in git or any other version control system like large graphic files - but that must be syncs with the project in OneDrive as well.

Comment: Hi, did you try to change NODE_PATH environment variable ? What dependencies manager do you use ? yarn has an option for that.

Comment: I'm using npm and NODE_PATH is not set (and make it sense to set it globally, since every project/app has to have different node_modules path?)